# How to initialise transient values when using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a DataContext and a Table, defined like so:

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<MyItem> MyItems;

    public MyDataContext(string location) : base(location) { }
}

[Table(Name = "MyItems")]
public class MyItem
{
    // ID
    private string id;

    [Column(Storage = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        private set { id = value; }
    }

    private MyDataContext db;
    private MyTransitiveObject obj;

    public MyItem() {}

    public MyItem(MyDataContext db, MyTransitiveObject obj)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

When I create a new `MyItem` for the table, there's no problem as I call the `MyItem(MyDataContext db, MyTransitiveObject obj)` constructor anyway:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(someLocation);
MyItem myItem = new MyItem(db, someObj);
db.MyItems.Add(myItem);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

However, if I want to retrieve a bunch of rows from the database, the transitive members would, of course, not be set. I'll need to initialise them though, before doing any work with the retrieved objects.

The only solution I can think of is to *make the members global* and go through all the queried objects and set them before doing any other operations with them. But this isn't neat:

```
var q =
   from c in db.Customers
   select c;

var list = q.ToList();

foreach (MyItem m in list)
{
    q.Db = db;
    q.Obj = someObj;
}

/* Do something with list */
```

Any ideas what the best way to handle this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        select new MyItem
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            // copy rest of c to MyItem
            Db = db,
            Obj = someObj
        };
```

This wraps up the conversion into the query so you don't have to loop over result set. It does seem odd to need to store the context with each object though.

Though it does mean that if you add extra columns to your table you have to update the `MyItem` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Will the DataContext still be able to maintain the identity of the queried objects, i.e. if one would make the same query twice, would it still return the same objects (as is the usual case)?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd like to store context and database reference within every element. I think you should rethink your design at the first place.

You could extend your `select` statement to create element using your constructor, but it couldn't be translated to SQL, so you have to get elements first. However, you don't have to make your fields public.

```
var q =
   from c in db.Customers
   select c;

var list = q.ToList()
            .Select(e => new MyItem(db, someObj) { Id = e.Id })
            .ToList();
```

`q.ToList()` is necessary to split execution between LINQ to SQL (getting all elements) and LINQ to Objects (creating new elements using your constructor). It could be replaced with `AsEnumerable()` as well.